# Return the first match from a large text document

Tags: .net, regex

I am new to regex and am trying to learn how to pull the information we need using regex. I believe I understand the basics, just haven't been able to find a way to get only the first match using `.net`.

I am trying to get the account number from a large text document that was created from an internet bill. The account numbers may or may not be at the start of the line, but it should always be prefaced by "Account number". How do I get it to return the first match only?

Example:

```
Account number 8448 20 020 1561858 Customer code 3501  
Account number 8448 20 020 1561858
```

The expression I am trying can grab the correct number, but it selects both account numbers:

```
(?<=Account number )(\d+\s\d+\s?){2}
```

Expected return:

```
8448 20 020 1561858
```

Comment: out of `8448 20 020 1561858`, how much you want to capture? entire string?

Comment: I should have specified, thanks for asking. I want the entire account number `8448 20 020 1561858` but nothing else.

Comment: Please share your code, or more details on how you are using the regex. Try `var res = Regex.Match(input, @"(?s)\bAccount number\s+([\d\s]+).*").Groups[1].Value.Trim()`.

Comment: Thank you for your input @WiktorStribiżew, but as is stated in my question, I am trying to use regex only to pull the first match only, not both account numbers.

Comment: And it is [capturing only 1 value](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)%5cbAccount+number%5cs%2b(%5b%5cd%5cs%5d%2b).*&i=Account+number+8448+20+020+1561858+Customer+code+3501++%0d%0aAccount+number+8448+20+020+4444444%0d%0adkwo4ehtfgui45rui%0d%0argrthgio4tgh%0d%0ag4tg). **Please share your code, or more details on how you are using the regex.**

Comment: I have shared the code. As I stated, I want to use regex alone, just the `.net` flavor in order to pull just the first match. As it is currently, it returns 2 groups. I guess I could have explained it a little better, but the regex line should be the only thing I'm testing to get the first match in the text document. There are plenty of other locations that the account number is located, but I only want the first. I can't change the `.net` code to only pull the first group, although I can see that would be easier.

Comment: Well, that changes the subject. You need a regex that gets the match value, or that can *capture* it? The regex I provided above [should *capture*](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)%5cbAccount+number%5cs%2b(%5b%5cd%5cs%5d%2b).*&i=Account+number+8448+20+020+1561858+Customer+code+3501++%0d%0aAccount+number+8448+20+020+1561854) the first instance into Group 1. Another idea (an inefficient one, because you have not specified what tool/environment you are using) is using a kind of a tempered greedy token inside a positive lookbehind anchored at the start (see next comment....)

Comment: [`(?s)(?<=\A(?:(?!\bAccount number\s+\d).)*\bAccount number\s+)\d+(?:\s+\d+)*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)(%3f%3c%3d%5cA(%3f%3a(%3f!%5cbAccount+number%5cs%2b%5cd).)*%5cbAccount+number%5cs%2b)%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cd%2b)*&i=Account+number+8448+20+020+1561858+Customer+code+3501++%0d%0aAccount+number+8448+20+020+1561854)

Comment: Any feedback? Is it working now?

Comment: I suggest closing as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is good enough. It just captures extra space(*you can trim it later*). Also you have to modify capturing group a bit like this to capture entire digits

```
(?<=Account number )((?:\d+\s\d+\s?){2})
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS4xM6/1)**

**or simply**

```
(?<=Account number )(\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS4xM6/2)**

`.net` code

```
var pattern = "(?<=Account number )((?:\\d+\\s\\d+\\s?){2})";
var input = "Account number 8448 20 020 1561858 Customer code 3501\nAccount number 8448 20 020 1561858";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = rgx.Match(input);

while (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

**[.net fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7EqSnn)**

If you want only first match, then you can use

```
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
}
```

Comment: It is still getting both possible account numbers. In case there is an error on the account number or if the text document has more than one account number, I am trying to get just the first match.

Comment: @Histerical what is the output you are getting?

Comment: I apologize for my confusion, still getting a grasp on how `regex` works. Your answer works well, I was trying to find a solution using just regex to only have 1 group selected and not 2.

Comment: @Histerical i didn't understood you..can you please elaborate?

Comment: My goal is to have just regex find the first solution and that will be pulled into `.net`. I understand now how `.net` could select the first group. Is there a way for regex to grab just the first match only?

Comment: @Histerical i am not able to understand the meaning of first match..what do you want to extract in your example?

Comment: As the regex goes through the text and it finds the first match from the top of the document, I am looking for it to stop and only have that 1 group.

Comment: @Histerical see it **[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z19gEW)**..there are two string separated by new line..only first match is returned

Comment: Yes that works well! But as I said, I am trying to see if I can get regex to return only the first. I understand that `.net` is capable of that, but with our current code, it pulls every group from regex. Because of the other things it pulls, I can't change that, so I'm trying to find a way for regex to do by itself.

Comment: @Histerical i don't understand..i don't see pulling it every group..you need to return the first capturing group

Comment: @Histerical and where are you testing it?

Comment: I am not sure how else I can explain what I am trying to do. I have a large text file that lists the account number at least 4-5 times. I am trying to pull only the first group using `regex`. Before it gets pulled into `.net`.

Comment: @Histerical did you unchecked the `g` flag?

Comment: How do I do that? I am not seeing that on this tester. Although I have seen it on others.

Comment: @Histerical i don't think its possible..there is a hack as told by Wiktor using `(?s)(?<=Account number )((?:\\d+\\s\\d+\\s?){2}).*`..it find only one match but hoghlights all..i don't think its possible to do there

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help! I wish there was a solution, but I will just have to find a workaround with our current `.net` code.